# Sata3 port count on modern intel chipsets - has been 8 or 10, now 6. Is there something I'm missing?

Tags: intel-rst, chipset

I'm comparing modern chipsets - my workstation is a top-end Ivy Bridge era X79 platform. While it's still near the top-end for performance, one area it's showing its age is the connectivity in the chipset.

As the CPU capability is good enough, I'm happy to upgrade to something more modern but less than cutting edge.

So I've been looking at [X79 compared to Z97, X99, Z170, Z270,X299,Z370 on Intel's compare site](https://ark.intel.com/compare/64015,82012,81761,90591,98088,98089,122941,125903) to get an idea where to pitch my upgrade, and one thing that's striking is the count of SATA 6G ports. X79=2 (problem), Z97=6 (decent), X99=10 (good)... and then Z170 onward with the exception of X299, back to just 6 ports again (whaat?)

It seems to be related to SATA6 being de-emphasised to make more lanes available for PCIe connected storage, and indeed the specs show PCIe device handling in the next row below the SATA port count, but this puzzles me overall. I've looked up reviews of the Z170 and they're nice and glowing - and imply everything got larger and they say nothing about any drop in SATA 6G port count.

I use the chipset SATA ports for soft RAID on non-crucial data, so it's useful to me. To be honest 6 or 8 would be enough, but I like to understand what I'm buying, and I like my drives directly connected on the chipset if I can (seems to be more reliable and less CPU draw).

Is my information correctly interpreted and what are the implications? More specifically:

- Are the PCIe connections able to substitute for the reduced SATA6 chipset connections and get RST working if one has >6 traditional SATA HDDs (or is some suitable board/interposter required)?
- Will I lose anything if I move to these but have say 8 traditional HDD/SSDs?

Comment: From apractical standpoint: If you are using traditional HDD (not SSDs) why even connect them to SATA6? SATA3 is still able to push around 270MB/sec and then is enough for harddisks. Especially if you want to keep the older drives around. For SSD's this is ofc not true, but for those you want a M2 sockets and NVMe SSDs.

Comment: As for what you asked: Most end users do not neeed many SATA (2 or 3) ports. And the consumer chipssets are made to be sold be the mayority of the people. If you want something uncommon you get pushed to non standard solutions. For Intel this seems a push to Xeons systems. Alternatively AMD is providing more PCI-e lanes and more options for SATA. Which makes sense from a marketing point.

Comment: @Hennes - there were command optimisations built into SATA 3 (6g) that weren't in the SATA 2 (3g) version, and are useful for optimising disk handling. I'm not sure how crucial they are to my workload but as the workload is heavy, queue optimisation and asynchronous/isochronous handling might be beneficial for my HDD use, even if the disks can't use the extra speed of a 6g connection.

Comment: Good point. One which you can benchmark. IUf it turns out to make a noticeable difference then Jaroslav Kucera is correct. You did not mention an OS. If not windows and lots of disks take a look at ZFS. Depending on what your tasks are you might get a huge boost with ZFS and ARC on a small SSD.

Comment: I'm on ZFS for my file server; the number of disks means I'm primarily using PCIE HBAs more than the mainboard ports. So this question is more for my workstation where I won't be using ZFS but instead windows. I've found the Intel fake raid works fine for non-server, the only time I lost data in the last 10 years was when I trialled an LSI RAID card instead. But the port count reduction bothers me because all I need is 2 x raid1 + system + cache SSDs, and that's 6 disks. Temporarily add 2 or 4 more to copy/reorganise/move a raid volume and ... will I be able to connect them? Had that before.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options these days.

1) Accept the Z170 (Z370 doesn't provide anything better speaking of SATA ports)

2) Buy additional PCI-E SATA controller (some cheap Axago/Kouwell etc.)

3) Consider AMD Ryzen platform. The X370 (6xSATA + 2xSATA Express + 1xNVME) with AM4. Each SATA Express port functions as either two SATA 3.0 ports or 2 PCI Express Gen3 lanes. So in total, you can have your 10 SATA devices connected. The performance is similar to the Intel offer and AM4 will for sure be able to handle few more generations of AMD Ryzen processors (which isn't usual on the Intel platform...).

If I'd buy new PC these days, I'd only consider option 3 as of the future perspective.